# Data Pop Up in same area of Google Maps api

Tags: arrays, google-maps-api-3, popup, bounce

In the Google Maps API I have set the various location in the Map and set out the Location with their unique address when I try to click on the location the address pop up box should have to be appear on the location place but now in my map when I click anywhere the pop up box shown up in the one place.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you open your infoWindow on your marker's onClick listener like this:

```
 var contentString = marker.getPosition().toString();
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });

 marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
```

Here's a complete sample implementation using [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows) that you can try: https://jsfiddle.net/smga08/anw2hfot/14/